# Creating Xml vs Creating Views Dynamically

Tags: android, xml, performance

My layout will have nested weights and will be in complex view-pager structure. Thus i want to do everything dynamically instead of creating them in xml file.

So what i wonder is, does ***creating  dynamically*** improve performance a lot? Especially in the conditions above? I will be still using nested weights but this time the phone will not have to deal with xml parsing. Or Should i just ignore and do everything in xml?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how often will you  build your layout?

Comment: Instead of using nested weights, maybe consider using [`PercentRelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html).

Answer (score 0):

Creating your structure dynamically is a good idea specially if the user can add objects a lot of time (or you in the future when you add new fonctionalities).

If your layout is fixed, maybe it will be easier and it will load fastier in xml.

*For an example, in a note application, you have no choice to add all element programatically.*

Comment: Thank you for answer, well it is fixed, for the note application part, generally you use listview with footer anyway =).  Someone suggested {PercentRelativeLayout} . What do you think?

Comment: You'r welcome. To be honnest i never used PercentRelativeLayout so i can't tell you :)